# How can I send data from detail to master in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisplitviewcontroller

You can show my design in the image(storyboard). I have a Table View Controller which has a collection cell inside the table view cell.

To make a horizontal slider, I designed program like this. However the problem is I do not know how can I send my data(which is in the collection cell) to the Master.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}
```

I think I need to make sth. in here, but I cannot create a segue and also cannot reach SplitViewController. Maybe I'm in the wrong place. Is there any hint or new story about this program?

Please note that I use alamofire to get data, and also you can look it second pic to what I'm trying to do.

[image]

[image]